# Can there be any other form of Visualisations for DBSCAN aside from ScatterPlot?

Tags: python, dbscan

I have a dataframe of size 122 rows × 1343 columns. I have trained the dataframe with DBSCAN model, but from what i know, i can only select 2 columns of the dataframe to plot visuals for output. Is there any other way where i can plot the clusters for all 1343 columns ?

Comment: You need to use [PCA](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html?highlight=pca#sklearn.decomposition.PCA), [TSNE](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.manifold.TSNE.html) or similar, to reduce the number of dimensions to a number that can be plotted.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the response. Yes currently i am doing that. But i was wondering if i could capture the full characteristics of the dataset without using dimension reduction (PCA), and visualise it.

Comment: If you knew how to do that then maybe you could time travel.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Appreciate it alot